# Raspberry PI Samba share inaccessible from windows 10

Tags: windows-iot, windows, samba

I'm trying to configure my PI to use as a fileserver, but after reading every  tutorial on this from google, I still can not figure out what is wring with my settings.

/media/pi/USBHDD permissions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /media/pi/USBHDD
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 28 18:45 MediaShare
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 11  2016 System Volume Information
```

Samba config:

```
[MediaShare]
        path = /media/pi/USBHDD/MediaShare
        writeable = yes
        only guest = yes
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
        browseable = yes
        public = yes
```

What I get when I try to access it:

[image]

I'm a beginner unix user. I'm going bald over this, please help!

Comment: I've seen this tutorial [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/) suggested on many questions, so I've done it from scrap, still no results.

Comment: This started to happen to me on Windows 10 recently. It worked fine for years. It must some new "no password" default policy in the registry. I have not worked it out yet.

Comment: It's good to know someone else have bumbed into this. I'll try to fiddle with it, maybe find something.

Comment: I think the username needs to be something like `<something>/Guest` and blank password. I saw this pop up on another Win10 machine yesterday and it worked. I am looking for more details on this now.

Comment: So I've tried for some time now, and still no results, managed to take ownership of the external drive to the pi user, so now no root involved. But still, as I log in, I still get the access denied response. This means, that the user/password is correct. I have no idea what could deny my access anymore... samba accepts my login, and the drive is owned by pi.

Comment: Yes the same for me. I can put root/password to loginto samba.. but it wont accept nouser and nopassword like before. Like I said I saw some account by default on another machine show as `guest` ? and blank password. It worked but that was not my machine

Comment: Okay, I've figured this one out. I messed up the config, further down below my share it contained a line "valid users = %s", so of course no user could access the share. Also I've set up the default mount with the option user, so now it belongs to the user pi.

Comment: hmm ok. Can you post your confis as an answer please.

Comment: @Puppetier: for me with this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/ that you mention, this helps: `sudo smbpasswd -a backups` (or any other user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this. I messed up the config, further down below my share it contained a line "valid users = %s", so of course no user could access the share.

What finally worked for me:

```
[global]
security = user
usershare allow guests = yes

[MediaShare]
path = /media/USBHDD/MediaShare
```

Everything else is the default. This way I can log in with users added with smbpasswd.

The important part is making sure, that you declare your share before or after the home share. My main problem was writing inside the home share, so some settings stuck with me.